# XML Element: Is a child of its own allowed

Tags: xml

I'm absolutely new to XML, but I was asked the following task. We are trying to build a structure in which XML Elements will have it's own as a child. And I'm not sure if it's allowed and possible.
Up to now I didn't find a fitting answer.
The structure look like that:

```
<tree>
   <name> Name1 </name>
   <tree>
      <tree>
      <name> Name2 </name>
         <tree>
         <name> Name2 </name>
         </tree>
      </tree>
   </tree>
   <tree>
   <name> Name3 </name>
      <tree>
      <name> Name4 </name>
      </tree>
   </tree>
</tree>
```

Is this allowed in XML?
If not, how can this structure be mapped in XML?

Answer (score 0):

No. The above structure is not allowed because the XML is not [*well-formed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).
You have opening tags `<tree>` without the corresponding closing tags `</tree>`.

To make it well-formed, the below is one possibility:

```
<tree>
   <name> Name1 </name>
   <tree>
      <tree>
         <name> Name2 </name>
         <tree>
            <name> Name2 </name>
         </tree>
      </tree>
   </tree>
   <name> Name3 </name>
   <tree>
      <name> Name4 </name>
      <tree />
   </tree>
</tree>
```

Here every opening tag has exactly one closing tag. Also the are empty tags `<tree />`. Which opening tag matches what closing tag is indicated by the indentation.

Comment: Yes, sorry. As I wrote this question, I didn't think of posting a well formed code, because I was focused on my question if an element can have a child of it's own kind. I fixed the code so that it should be well formed.
Thanks for your comment!
But if I understand you correctly, it is permissible, if you do it right ... :-)

Comment: The structure I posted above is well-formed. If you asked if a `tree` node can have `tree` children, the answer is yes.